# Fill QGIS form by clicked attribute

Tags: qgis

Does anyone know if it could be possible to fill the field of the layer for which the form is open with some data from another layer by clicking on one of its object?

As an example, let's say I have a layer with some streets and another one with some buildings. In the first there is the name of the streets for each line, and in the other a field referencing the name of its adress' street. I would like to be able, instead of writing eveytime the name of the street related, to simply click on the linear object of the street and fill the field of the building that fit.

Answer (score 3):

Not as you would like it, by simple clicking.

You could, for example use v.distance from the GRASS-toolbox to add the name of the street to buildings based on proximity. Though this may produce faulty outcomes for buildings on corners or which are rather remote from the street.

/edit: You could use - in this specific example - points which are situated directly at the street/line geometry and share an UID with the corresponding building, thus allowing you to attach the data added to the points later on to the buildinngs. Or go all in and build a spatial database. Depends on how much you have to work with the data later on. Still, no easy way, sorry.